# Am I Doing a Linear Approximation on $\sqrt x$ Correctly?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

This was the question assigned to me:

> Let $f$ be the function defined by $f(x)=\sqrt x$. Using the line tangent to the graph at $x=9$, what is the approximation of $f(9.3)$?

I know the formula for linear approximation is $$f(x)+f'(x)\Delta x$$ I plugged it in and got: $$3+\frac16(.3)$$ Doing the simple calculation results in $3.05$.
I do not see any problems with how I did this problem. However, I am a beginner and feel I may be missing something. Was this done correctly?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Your steps are correct. If you are still unsure about your anwser, you can check that by calculating $\sqrt{9.3}$ on google which is $\approx 3.0496$ and that is pretty close to your answer.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Looks right to me. Also you can do blockquotes by putting `>` in front of text, and the preview function should indicate when your post is unreadable (e.g. when latex goes off-screen).

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how people do that.

Comment: Just a very minor point : write $f(x+\Delta x)=f(x)+f'(x)\Delta x$ or, better $f(x+\Delta x)\approx f(x)+f'(x)\Delta x$. Otherwise, this is very correct.

Comment: Your procedure is good. You may be interested in checking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks correct.   In fact, if you use a calculator to compute $\sqrt{9.3},$ you’ll see that your linear approximation is very good.